# How to use multiple play buttons in a single page with Howler JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, howler.js

In [this](http://codepen.io/drhouse7x/pen/XjvQWm) example, I'm using [Howler JS](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0/examples/player) as a music player and I need to create a playlist by class objects and be able to use multiple play/pause buttons in the same page.

So for the playlist I did:

```
var titx;
var filx;
var idx;
var myplax = [];

$.each($('.btnplay'), function(index, value) { 
    titx = $(this).attr("title");
    filx = $(this).attr("data-track-name");
    idx = $(this).attr("data-id");
    myu = {
      id: idx,
      title: titx,
      file: filx,
      howl: null        
    }
  myplax.push(myu);
});

var player = new Player(myplax);
```

Then for fire the play button with multiple play/pause buttons in page, I tried with jQuery like this:

```
$(".btnplay").click(function(){
  player.play();   
});
$(".btnpause").click(function(){
  player.pause();   
});
```

But when I click any play buttons it starts to play every time the first song.
Also If I click the second button (the one at the top) the jQuery animate instead the first button (the one at the bottom).

However the playlist works great, but how can I fix the issue for the play button?

Comment: from what i see your player accepts a array, how does play know what is the current element in the array to play it?

Comment: @madalinivascu yes that's my problem...the playlist works because is indexed instead for the play button `$(".btnplay").click(function(){
  player.play();   
});` it's not...I thought that jQuery could make it (I mean select the correct `this`)